# How to map req.body contains array of object to a model in node js for insertmany

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I have developing an application in mean stack. In this i want to insert multiple darts at a time.
I am insert req.body directly its working fine...

```
 // make a connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dart', { useNewUrlParser: true });

// get reference to database
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function () {
  console.log("Connection Successful!");
})
app.post('/dart_create', function (req, res) {
   console.log('Request body output '
     + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  try {
    db.collection("darts").insertMany(**req.body**);
    console.log("Data inserted successfully");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

But i dont want to pass the object directly to the table. I have a dart model. But i dont know how to assign the value to dart model...

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {

    console.log("inside create data:");
    console.log("Body Obj:" +JSON.stringify(req.body));
    // Create a Dart
    const dart = new Dart({        
        userName: req.body.userName, 
        taskDate: req.body.taskDate,
        FromTime: req.body.FromTime,
        ToTime: req.body.ToTime,
        plannedTask: req.body.plannedTask,
        remarks: req.body.remarks
    });
    // Save Dart in the database
    console.log("dart Obj:" +JSON.stringify(req.body));
    dart.save()
    .then(data => {
        req.flash("success", "Dart "+dart.userName+" for the date"+dart.taskDate +" Inserted Succesfully");
        res.send(req.flash('success'));
        console.log('Data saved successfully');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error');
        res.status(500).send({

            message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Dart."
        });
    });
```

I have tried the above code... But dart Obj:console is empty only... how to do this...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var dartSchema = new Schema({
    userName: String,
    taskDate: String,
    FromTime: String,
    ToTime: String,
    plannedTask: String,
    remarks: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('darts', dartSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {

console.log("inside create data:");
console.log("Body Obj:" +JSON.stringify(req.body));
// Create a Dart
const dart = new Dart();    
    dart.userName = req.body.userName; 
    dart.taskDate = req.body.taskDate;
    dart.FromTime = req.body.FromTime;
    dart.ToTime = req.body.ToTime;
    dart.plannedTask = req.body.plannedTask;
    dart.remarks = req.body.remarks;
// Save Dart in the database
console.log("dart Obj:" +JSON.stringify(req.body));
dart.save()
.then(data => {
    req.flash("success", "Dart "+dart.userName+" for the date"+dart.taskDate +" Inserted Succesfully");
    res.send(req.flash('success'));
    console.log('Data saved successfully');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error');
    res.status(500).send({

        message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Dart."
    });
});
```